# How to turn on plugins only for admins in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Just like the title says. I want to test out a new plugin for my Wordpress site, but I only want the admins to see the plugin (it is a big plugin with a big change, so I don't want regular users to see it before it's all set up).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Guess that question is out of topic

Answer (score 1):

You can try it on your localhost.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Test_Driving_WordPress